# How to allow for manual HTML & CSS changes?

Tags: 7, theming, wysiwyg

I'm using CK Editor to insert a table into my content (**Body** field).

I would like to set a background color, so I extended the `style="width:100%"` to be `style="background-color: #FFEEE4; color: black;width: 100%"`. And this by clicking on `Switch to plain text editor`.

But now, once I save, the `background-color` style disappears again (Test Format FULL HTML). How can I make it stick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to:

/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Advanced (for Filter HTML)

/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full (for Full HTML)

Then under Advanced Content Filter, select disabled.

[image]

**If the above does not do it**, depending on which one you are using (filter or full html) You need to go to

/admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html

OR

/admin/config/content/formats/full_html

#### **Uncheck the correct faulty and chopped off html box.**

[image]